# Template and CSS 404 when using dist directory from fountain-webapp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, digital-ocean, yo

I built a pretty simple webapp, here's a breakdown of what I've done so far:

1. Created an app using [fountain-webapp](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp)
2. Cloned the repo on a DigitalOcean droplet with a LAMP stack
3. Configured the Apache webroot to serve from `var/www/html/my-project/dist`
4. Ran `gulp build` to create the `dist` directory

I can hit the app itself and see the homepage but I'm getting 404s for every angular html template I request and I also get a 404 for FontAwesome. It looks like the requests are being made to directories outside `dist` which is also very confusing.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `dist` directory? Could my gulp tasks be causing the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I see your url `https://nelsoncf.com/dist/`, and you have two message in console. 
Loading failed for the  with source dist:21
Loading failed for the  with source dist:23
I think you need check your files

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had forgotten about this post but it was actually an issue with custom fonts and fountain's gulp config. See [this issue](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp/issues/166) for more details.